# How do I insert a space in a word using a MySQL string function?

Tags: mysql, regex, function, select, logic

How would I go about inserting a space in a word using a MySQL string
function?

I have a GPS co-ordinate saved in my gps column as such

`S2829.080,E2850.683`

I would like the output to be :

`S28 29.080,E28 50.683`

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

**SOLUTION UPDATE :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');

SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', LEFT(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',1),3),MID(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',1),4,LENGTH(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',1)))) AS
latitude;

SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', LEFT(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',1),3),MID(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',2),4,LENGTH(SPLIT_STR("S2829.080,E2850.683",',',2)))) AS
longitude;
```

I have since "Normalized" my database and changed the JS form by adding 2 columns
for longitude and latitude.

Thank you all

Comment: Is the pattern always the same: 3chars, space, number, comma, 3chars, space, number?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, the pattern is always the same. The JS app has a regex in place to check for this pattern but it was implemented a bit late. /A-Z{1}[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

use `concat()`,`left()`,`mid()` mysql functions:

```
update table set columnname=concat(LEFT(columnname,3),' ',MID(columnname,4,LENGTH(columnname)))
```

Assuming your space will always be after 3 char in your column value

BTW it will not work if you storing comma separated values under single column. and that is drawback of such table schema.

You should `Normalize` your database

You should make parent child table in-stead of comma separated values

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have update my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split the first 3 characters and the rest here is one way

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( " ", LEFT( columname 3 ) , SUBSTRING( columnname FROM 4 ) ) FROM tablename
```